# Debug link missing in PyCharm after changing from Python 2 to Python 3

Tags: python-2.7, pycharm, python-3.5

I'm not sure if this is a setting somewhere, but after changing my project from Python 2.7 to Python 3.5 I lost the debugging link in the Run window.

Here is a screen shot running Python 2.7:

[image]

Here is the screen shot running Python 3.5:

[image]

Am I missing a plugin or is there a setting somewhere for this? I don't want to hunt and peck for the link every time I debug a new project.

I'm running PyCharm version 4.5.3

**Update**

When `app.debug = True` it will hide the link, but when set to `False`, it shows the link (for Python 3 only)

Here is my pip list:

```
Flask (0.10.1)
Flask-Login (0.3.2)
Flask-SQLAlchemy (2.1)
itsdangerous (0.24)
Jinja2 (2.8)
MarkupSafe (0.23)
pip (7.1.2)
PyMySQL (0.6.7)
setuptools (18.2)
SQLAlchemy (1.0.9)
Werkzeug (0.11.2)
WTForms (2.0.2)
XlsxWriter (0.7.7)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is coming from the version of `Werkzeug`. In `Werkzeug 0.11.02`, the project link will not display if `app.debug` is set to `True`

Taken from [WerkZeug](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/), you directly call `run_simple`, while passing in the `host`, `port`, and `app`, as a workaround.

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask('my_app')
app.debug = True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from werkzeug.serving import run_simple
    run_simple('localhost', 4000, app)
```

Comment: This did it. Thank you.